# Integrating custom Authentication provider with JAX-RS server

Tags: authentication, jax-rs

I'm developing a simple JAX - RS server and I need to implement Authentication and Authorization. I have found in other posts that the standard way is to use the standard Java EE web servlet container security with role-mapping in conjunction with OAuth, Form-based Authentication or Basic Authentication.

My problem is my company has a custom Authentication Provider accessible by an EJB client. The Authentication provider takes username and password in input and return a UserObject with a series of rights associated with it. If the rights list contain the one associated with my REST server, then the user is also authorized to ask for resources, otherwise a CustomAuthorizationException is thrown. In fact this is a 'one-shot Authorization', so i could enforce it with additional servlet container standard authorization.

This is an example:

```
String username = //acquire username;
String password = // acquire password;

UserObject user = null;

try {
    user = authenticationClient.login(username, password);
    if(user == null){
       //erro message and forward to login page
    }

    verifyAuthorization(user);

} catch (CustomAuthorizationException e1) {
    //manage exception
} catch (CustomAuthenticationException e2) {
    //manage exception
}
```

How can I integrate this with JAX - RS standards?

Comment: What JAX-RS implementation/version are you using?

Comment: I'm on Webshpere 8.5 so Java EE 6, JAX-RS 1.1 with the default WAS 8.5 implementation (Wink based). Anyway i'd like to write server agnostic code. Thanks